# Error with compiled Twig templates

Tags: templating, error-message

Occasionally, after deploying Craft, without warning I am unable to access the admin dashboard and get the following PHP error:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting '&' or variable (T_VARIABLE) in /var/www/html/releases/1444051402/craft/storage/runtime/compiled_templates/9/f/9fb1fb61cba0ba044bdd7fb03e82130398321f3315b85408215cc636d2ff3f4c.php on line 177
```

I am really struggling to replicate the issue. It doesn't occur on my local development environment: it only happens after a seemingly random amount of time sitting on my live server.

**Deleting the `compiled_templates` folder in `/craft/storage/runtime` fixes the issue** but I do not do what is causing it to occur in the first place.

Comment: Do you have a byte-level PHP caching enabled on the box?  i.e. opcache/APC cache, etc.